# Use awk output in non-standard command

Tags: bash, awk, output, pipe

I have some output from awk and some other commands I need put into a final command that is not part of the standard unix library so putting it into the awk command itself doesn't work.

My command I have now is below and gives the following output

`root@amc-d24a4-rf4:~# for x in {0..19}; do   showbbchan $x | grep 60.2; done | sed 's/://g' | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, '-16.6'}'`

```
11 TX3 -8100000 -16.6
12 TX1 12700000 -16.6
13 TX1 -3800000 -16.6
15 TX3 1500000 -16.6
16 TX3 -3300000 -16.6
17 TX1 17500000 -16.6
18 TX1 1000000 -16.6
19 TX3 6300000 -16.6
```

I need to put that output into a cfgbbchan (the non-standard command) command so it would look like

`cfgbbchan 11 TX3 -8100000 -16.6`
then

`cfgbbchan 12 TX1 12700000 -16.6` etc

I've tried using xargs and couldn't figure it out. It feels like I'm so close but can't figure out the last step.

Basically I need to take certain outputs from showbbchan and put them into cfgbbchan.

Example of showbbchan output

```
root@amc-d24a4-rf4:~# showbbchan 1
BB_Chan 1: RX0 -17700000 Hz 0.0 dB Selected:1 Enabled:1
BB_Chan 1: TX3 -17700000 Hz -16.6 dB Selected:1 Enabled:1
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `grep` nor `sed` when you're already using `awk`; also, `xargs` can do what you're looking for:

```bash
for x in {0..19}
do
    showbbchan "$x"
done |
awk '/60\.2/ { gsub(/:/,""); print $2, $3, $4, "-16.6" }' |
xargs -L 1 cfgbbchan
```

**note:** I guessed (maybe wrongly) that you wanted a "literal dot" instead of "any character" in the `60.2` regex

Comment: I get a syntax error when running this


root@amc-d24a4-rf4:~# for x in {0..19}; do showbbchan "$x"; done | awk '/60\.2/ {gsub(/:/,"") print $2, $3, $4, "-16.6" }'
awk: cmd. line:1: /60\.2/ {gsub(/:/,"") print $2, $3, $4, "-16.6" }
awk: cmd. line:1:                       ^ syntax error


The syntax error is pointing to the p in print

Comment: If you use it in one line then add a `;` before `print`